# Eclipse SonarQube plugin: run analysis on new project

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube, project, analysis

Is it possible to run an analysis on a project in eclipse, which isn't pushed to the SonarQube database yet?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not in the current version.

This will be available "soon" tho.